# Weak convergence of a net in $c_0 (\mathbb{N})$.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I try to prove the following result:

> Let $((x_n^{(i)}))_{i \in I} \subset c_0 (\mathbb{N})$ be a net. Suppose $(x_n^{(i)})  \xrightarrow[]{w} (x_n)$. Then $x_n^{(i)} \to x_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am aware of the characterisation $(x_n^{(i)})  \xrightarrow[]{w} (x_n)$ iff $f (x_n^{(i)})  \to  f(x_n)$ for all $f \in (c_0 (\mathbb{N}))^* \cong \ell^1 (\mathbb{N})$, but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that for any $k \in \Bbb N$, the projection $f_k$ satisfying
$$
f_k[(y^{(i)}] = y^{(i)}_k
$$
is a bounded linear functional.

Comment: Does this work for any net with arbitrary directed set $I$ as index set?

Comment: @user342207 it is the definition of "a net converges weakly" : $x^i \to x$ weakly iff for any $f \in (c_0)^*$ : $f(x^i) \to f(x)$ ?

Comment: @user342207 define it ?

Comment: @user342207 define the weak convergence of a net in $c_0$ in such a way it is not obvious it reduces to what I wrote..